# how to combine both update

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:

```
UPDATE images set show = 0 where show =1;
UPDATE images set show = 1 where id = $id;
```

'show' is a Boolean number 0 or 1, because only 1 image can show in all times.
I want use for an event, when I use above code, will display error: 
"MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use"
So, how to combined above coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql `show` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), therefore you need to put backticks around it if you would like to use it as a field name.

```
UPDATE images set `show` = 0 where show =1;
UPDATE images set `show` = 1 where id = $id;
```

I would not combine them into a single update statement, it would not be efficient because a single update would not really be able to use indexes, while these 2 updates would.

However, you can combine them if you really want to:

```
UPDATE images SET `show`=if(`show`=1,0,1)
WHERE `show`=1 OR ID=$id;
```

Comment: Because that is an example, 'show' is a reserved word, that i know, but my really word is different. And thanks you, it is work

Comment: But i think have a problem, because when $id is it same, so will became all 0. Example: id=1, show = 0; id=2, show=1, id=3, show =0; when i use UPDATE images SET `show`=if(`show`=1,0,1)
WHERE `show`=1 OR ID=2; then became all show are 0. ONLY ONE show is 1

Comment: OK, got your question in the end. If you set the flag to the existing record, then a single update will never work, since a single update statement never touches the same record twice. You should not issue the update statement in the first place if the flagged record does not change.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 UPDATE images SET show = (CASE
    WHEN show = 1 THEN 0
    WHEN id = $id THEN 1
    END) WHERE (show =1 OR id = $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
UPDATE images SET `show` = CASE
    WHEN `show` = 1 THEN 0
    WHEN id =$id THEN 1
    END;
```

Hope this will helps.